# How to apply texture pixels to cloud of points vertices?

Tags: javascript, webgl

I'm trying to move the pixels of an image on a texture onto a set of vertices, so I could use them as a point cloud, in WebGL.
One way to do this would be to
render the texture to a framebuffer, then use `gl.readPixels()` to move onto a JavaScript array, then move the array back to the GPU with `gl.bufferData()`.
Treating the data as vertices, the point cloud could be rendered with `gl.drawArrays()` using the `gl.POINTS` primitive.

But this requires that the data move from the GPU to the CPU and back again, this could become costly, especially for video.
Is there a way to move data directly from a texture to a vertex list, without leaving the GPU?

Any references, suggestions, or code examples greatly appreciated!

Comment: To do in one pass. You can gain access to the texture in the vertex shader. Create a set of 2D verts one for each pixel you want from the image and then  in the vertex shader convert the 2D vert to 3D (your point cloud) using the texture.

Comment: Thanks!  Just the tip I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Blindman67 for pointing out that you can access textures in the vertex shader, I didn't know this.  You can simply use texture2D(), working examples are https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/conformance-suites/2.0.0/conformance/rendering/vertex-texture-fetch.html for WebGL, and http://webglsamples.org/WebGL2Samples/#texture_vertex for WebGL2. A good search term is "WebGL vertex texture fetch". Don't waste time (as I did) following old links, and trying to get calls like texture2DLodEXT() to work.